# Issues with Multitail 5.2.11 Install on RHEL5.3

Tags: tail

I'm having some difficulty getting Multitail installed on a Linux box.  Their site mentions that Multitail requires the ncurses library, but systems like *BSD and Linux have this library by default.  The header files mentioned during the install lead me to believe that the ncurses library is not an existing library or a configuration file may not be pointed in the correct location.

When running the "make install" command I get the following:
    root@taspmociias304:/u01/multitail-5.2.11
    17:41:19 # make install
    gcc -funsigned-char -D`uname` -O2 -Wall -DVERSION=\"5.2.11\" -g  -DCONFIG_FILE=\"//etc/multitail.conf\"   -c -o     utils.o utils.c
    In file included from utils.c:34:
    mt.h:55:20: error: panel.h: No such file or directory
    mt.h:56:22: error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from utils.c:34:
    mt.h:127: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âWINDOWâ
    In file included from utils.c:36:
    globals.h:124: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_bottom_left_hand_cornerâ
    globals.h:125: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_bottom_right_hand_cornerâ
    globals.h:126: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_bottom_sideâ
    globals.h:127: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_left_sideâ
    globals.h:128: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_right_sideâ
    globals.h:129: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_top_left_hand_cornerâ
    globals.h:130: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_top_right_hand_cornerâ
    globals.h:131: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âbox_top_sideâ
    make: *** [utils.o] Error 1

Does anyone out there have experience with Multitail or any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to compile it anyway? You should use standard package manager that is provided by your OS to install it.

For Redhat/Fedora, use this:

```
sudo yum install multitail
```

For Debian/Ubuntu, use this:

```
sudo apt-get install multitail
```

I have installed it on my Ubuntu and Fedora boxes, and it worked by default, without needing to install any 3rd party repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Year old question but here's the answer:

You need ncurses

```
yum install ncurses-devel ncurses
```

Then it will compile properly.

Useful to install the last multitail 5.2.13 which the repositories do not carry for centos